# Servo not moving with PIR motion sensor

Tags: arduino-mega, servo

I am working on this code to turn a servo when the PIR motion sensor detects no motion, but it is not working.
Some symptoms include:

1. Servo is turning extremely slowly
2. PIR is not turning the servo
3. Servo is turning to incorrect angles

I have tried test programs, and when I type in the serial monitor, the servo turns (slowly and inaccurately) (I coded the serial monitor to do this). I have input from the PIR sensor but it is constantly high, even after waiting 2 minutes for it to initialize. My code and schematic are shown below.

[image: Schematic]

My code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  servo.attach(13);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Please wait");
  delay(60000);
}

void ifMos() {
  if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    int USER = 270;
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int USER = Serial.parseInt();
  servo.write(USER);
  Serial.println(USER);
  ifMos();
  delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: firget about the servo for now ... write the simplest code that lights an LED when motion is detected

Answer (score 1):

> firget about the servo for now ... write the simplest code that lights an LED when motion is detected –
> -jsotola

It worked! Thank you so much.
All I had to do was add the servo library, write to the servo and upload it. Only 21 lines of code! Final code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  servo.attach(13);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
    servo.write(270);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    servo.write(0);
  }
}
```

Thank you to everyone. This was my first time posting on stack exchange, and it was a huge success. Thank you again!